# How to update an item in an array of an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I have a list of people, each with an id. I have to add a tag to a newly created array for a person with a certain id. The json object 'students' already exists and I am updating it using its useState setStudents method but it seems to be returning an unidentified object back. My plan was as follows:

1. Map through the previousStudents
2. If the id matches (the person who I'm adding a tag to), then add the tag. The if statement to add a tag is there because the 'tags' property doesn't initially exist, so I make it on the first tag add
3. If the id doesn't match, just return that student

```
const updateStudent = (tag, id) => {
    setStudents((prevStudents) => {
      prevStudents.map((student) => {
        if (student.id !== id) return student;
        if (student.tags) {
          student["tags"].push(tag);
        } else {
          student["tags"] = [tag];
        }
        return student;
      });
    });
};
```

Sorry if my explanation was confusing but tldr: I'm just trying to add an item to an array of a specified object and it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: First of all you don't write all that code inside setStudents(). You decide the final array and then use it to directly update setStudents(). There is no prevStudent variable that is passed to function, then how are you using it inside it?  You've also not provided structure of student array, how we know what you are trying to push and even doing it correctly. Paste the original more code.

Comment: Please show more of the code you're trying to get working. A simple code pen or sandbox illustrating the bug would be ideal.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, but I seem to have figured it out using this resource: [link](https://dev.to/joelynn/react-hooks-working-with-state-arrays-2n2g). I couldn't really send more context on the problem as this is somewhat of an assessment. Thank you for the advice though, it aided in finding the solution. I will delete this post in a couple of hours as it's not really the best of questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "cleaner" approach would be something like this:

```
const updateStudent = (tag, id) => {

  // form a new students object
  let newStudents = students.map(student => {
    if(student.id === id) {
      student.tags? student.tags.push(tag) : student.tags = [tag];
    }
    return student;
  });

  setStudents(newStudents); // set the newly formed object to state
}
```

It is better to separate the update logic from setting the state

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for, I'll make sure to separate the logic from now on.